# Copying char arr[64] to char arr[] can cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault

```
typedef struct {
    int num;
    char arr[64];
} A;

typedef struct {
    int num;
    char arr[];
} B;
```

I declared `A* a;` and then put some data into it. Now I want to cast it to a `B*`.

```
A* a;
a->num = 1;
strcpy(a->arr, "Hi");

B* b = (B*)a;
```

Is this right?
I get a segmentation fault sometimes (not always), and I wonder if this could be the cause of the problem.

I got a segmentation fault even though I didn't try to access to `char arr[]` after casting.

Comment: I rolled back your changes. See the comments under @Yunnosch's answer. Changing code to such extent is bad [SO] netiquette.

Comment: The first one was a mistake .. should I have to let this question be though it wasn't my intention ?

Comment: With all due respect, no one was forcing you to post irrelevant code. You should prepare your [mcve] in advance. You are asking volunteers to help with your problem, and then shift the goal on them without warning. It's unfair, and I personally think is a bit rude. You can always [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Okay, but I want to say that ...I saw the Yunnosch's comments and decided to roll back my question before you did. Also I already felt sorry to Yunnosch unless you gave me some lesson. I could be aware of what you say and do it myself. The reason why I commented like above was just that I felt not so good on your speaking. Anyway, I'm sorry If you felt I was rude .

Comment: I am fine. As long as you keep the question and don't change it, I will happily keep my little rep-present and not carry a grudge. Please do not carry a grudge against StoryTeller either. You are a rare case of insight, take that as a compliment. Experienced users often have to step in to make the less reflective askers stay fair. And the affected answerers are grateful if they do not have to do the rollback themselves, it "looks" better. Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

This defines a pointer variable

```
A* a;
```

There is nothing it is cleanly pointing to, the pointer is non-initialised.

This accesses whatever it is pointing to

```
a->num = 1;
strcpy(a->arr, "Hi");
```

Without allocating anything to the pointer beforehand (by e.g. using `malloc()`) this is asking for segfaults as one possible consequence of the undefined behaviour it invokes.

Comment: Maybe, better, `...asking for undefined behaviour`? segmentation fault is not guaranteed, you know.

Comment: @SouravGhosh While you are correct, it is not asking for UB, it **is**. Isn't it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Not guaranteed, sometimes what you ask for you do not get. ;-)

Comment: I edited the code in my question. Could you check the code again ?

Comment: Please undo your changes. It changes the question completly. That is considered a "moving target" question and considered unfair towards people who have answered the first version (which admittedly affects me in this case).

Comment: Please ask a new question to get help with that different code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to [Yunnosch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606328/2371524), which identifies the problem correctly. Let's assume you do it correctly and either write just

```
A a;
```

which gives you an object of automatic storage duration when declared inside a function, or you dynamically allocated an instance of `A` like this:

```
A *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
if (!a) return -1; // or whatever else to do in case of allocation error
```

Then, the next thing is your cast:

```
B* b = (B*)a;
```

This is not correct, types `A` and `B` are not compatible. Here, it will probably work in practice because the `struct` members **are** compatible, but beware that strange things can happen because the compiler is allowed to assume `a` and `b` point to different objects because their types are not compatible. For more information, read on the topic of what's commonly called the *strict aliasing rule*.

You should also know that an incomplete array type (without a size) is only allowed as the very last member of a `struct`. With a definition like yours:

```
typedef struct {
    int num;
    char arr[];
} B;
```

the member `arr` is allowed to have any size, but it's **your responsibility** to allocate it correctly. The size of `B` (`sizeof(B)`) doesn't include this member. So if you just write

```
B b;
```

you can't store *anything* in `b.arr`, it has a size of `0`. This last member is called a *flexible array member* and can only be used correctly with dynamic allocation, adding the size manually, like this:

```
B *b = malloc(sizeof *b + 64);
```

This gives you an instance `*b` with an `arr` of size 64. If the array doesn't have the type `char`, you must multiply manually with the size of your member type -- it's not necessary for `char` because `sizeof(char)` is by definition `1`. So if you change the type of your array to something different, e.g. `int`, you'd write this to allocate it with 64 elements:

```
B *b = malloc(sizeof *b + 64 * sizeof *(b->arr));
```

Comment: Nice salomonic solution (even more for the non-technical problem here than anything else; technically it is of course also nice). My respect.

Comment: @Yunnosch well thanks, I wasn't sure what's going on here, but assumed from the comments this first error wasn't (all) OP was confused with, therefore just added some more info :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are confusing two different topics. In C99/C11 `char arr[];` as the last member of a structure is a *Flexible Array Member* (FAM) and it allows you to allocate for the structure itself and `N` number of elements for the flexible array. However -- you must allocate storage for it. The FAM provides the benefit of allowing one-allocation and one-free where there would normally be two required. (In C89 a similar implementation went by the name *struct hack*, but it was slightly different).

For example, `B *b = malloc (sizeof *b + 64 * sizeof *b->arr);` would allocate storage for `b` *plus* 64-characters of storage for `b->arr`. You could then copy the members of `a` to `b` using the proper `'.'` and `'->'` syntax.

A short example can illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCHAR 64   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct {
    int num;
    char arr[NCHAR];
} A;

typedef struct {
    int num;
    char arr[];   /* flexible array member */
} B;

int main (void) {
    A a = { 1, "Hi" };
    B *b = malloc (sizeof *b + NCHAR * sizeof *b->arr);

    if (!b) {
        perror ("malloc-b");
        return 1;
    }

    b->num = a.num;
    strcpy (b->arr, a.arr);

    printf ("b->num: %d\nb->arr: %s\n", b->num, b->arr);

    free (b);
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_fam
b->num: 1
b->arr: Hi
```

Look things over and let me know if that helps clear things up. Also let me know if you were asking something different. It is a little unclear exactly where you confusion lies.